# Implementing a datalogger in bash

Tags: bash

Hi I'm a newby in Bash scripting.

I need to log a data stream from a specific IP address and generate a logfile for each day as "file-$date.log"  (i.e at 00:00:00 UT close the previous day file and create the correspondig to the new one)
I need to show data stream on screen while it is logged in a file

I try this solution but not works well because never closesthe initial file 
apparently the condition check never executes while the first command of the pipe it is something different to an constant string like echo "something".

```
#!/bin/bash

log_data(){

 while IFS= read -r line ; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date -u  '+%j %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line";   done  

}

register_data() {
while : ;
    do 
    > stream.txt
    DATE=$(date -u "+%j %Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    HOUR=$(date -u "+%H:%M:%S")
    file="file-$DATE.log"


    while [[  "${HOUR}" != 00:00:00  ]];
    do 

        tail -f stream.txt | tee   "${file}"  
        sleep 1
        HOUR=$(date -u "+%H:%M:%S")

    done
     > stream.txt
done
}

nc -vn $IP $IP_port | log_data >> stream.txt &
register_data
```

I'll will be glad if someone can give me some clues to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you truncating `stream.txt` at two separate points of the loop? I don't understand the intended logic.

Comment: ...as for your loop, keep in mind that `tail -f` doesn't ever exit unless signaled, so how are you going to get back to the `while` to look at the hour again?

Comment: Also, needing to call `date` twice per second (for this code to work as intended) is extremely inefficient -- keep in mind that `date` is an external command (`/bin/date` or `/usr/bin/date`), so invoking it involves a `fork()`, `exec()`, `wait()`, and all the other fun involved in subprocesses. Frankly, it would be much easier to implement this efficiently if you were open to considering a different language.

Comment: Also, as implemented, it's very dangerous to assume that you'll get around to a given point in the loop within a certain amount of time -- even with the other logic fixed, if you went straight from `11:59:59` to `00:00:01` without passing through `00:00:00`, [which can easily happen: `sleep` doesn't promise to be exact] you'd never rotate the file. And that's assuming that `00:00:00` can ever happen; what actually follows 11:59:59 is 12:00:00.

Comment: Which version of bash are you using? Very new releases (4.3 definitely, perhaps 4.2 as well) has built-in date formatting built into `printf`, which would allow performance to be substantially improved.

Comment: Oh I see ! second ">stream.txt" is a cut & paste mistake!, ther is only one of such instances inside the while loop.

Comment: As you pointed, just you ansewer one of my doubts external commands that needs to be signaled can not be used because cause that never rotates the logs,

Comment: but if I replace "tail -f stream.txt: with "cat stream.txt" seems to work and rotate the log file. But the performance is bad and not always rotates the logs.

Comment: i'm using Bash 4.2 version

Comment: If I were trying to do this right -- really, properly right -- I wouldn't be using pure bash. I might have the `nc` part of the job running under `runit`, and the log rotation and management done by `svlogd`; that way, the only parts you're scripting yourself are two little one-liners, and everything else is done by special-purpose tools.

Comment: thanks again for your helpful comments, The purpose of such script is to log the datastream of a magnetometer installed in a remote location and the software provided by the magnetometer is useless because even in windows it doesn't works. Also the remote linux computer it is operated by other low skilled people unfamiliarized with programation .

Comment: I'll try to implement your suggestion I never worked with runit but I'll do my best effort.